# C language Issue simulating Lotka-Volterra model

Tags: c, simulation

Im a beginner programer and I need help with my simulation of the Lotka-Volterra model. I have to implement Euler and Verlet algorithm and I dont know if it is well done. In the model there is constant, V, my problem is that V is not conserved in time and I dont know why..I don't know what the results should be exactly, so I don't know if mine are right. V starts at one value but then oscillates between two values ​​and remains so until the end of the simulation. Nor do I know if I have correctly implemented the algorithms that are requested. Other issue is that I dont know how to treat the cases that the variables are less than one, that apparently doesnt have physical sense.
Thank you very much for the help.

I leave here the code that I have done so far, thanks for help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    
    #define DT 0.0625
    #define MAX 400
    #define EULER
    
    void feuler(double xn,double yn,double *xnext,double *ynext);
    void fverlet(double xn,double yn,double *xnext,double *ynext);
    
    double Cxx=1.0;
    double Cxy=0.2;
    double Cyy=0.2;
    double Cyx=0.01;
    
    int main()
    {
        double x;
        double y;
        double t;
        double xaux,yaux;
        double V,Vaux;
        FILE *f;
    
        x=20;
        y=6;
        t=0;

        f=fopen("PyD.txt","w");
        if (f==NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR");
        }
        else 
        {
            Vaux=Cyx*x-Cyy*log(x)+Cxy*y-Cxx*log(y);
            fprintf(f,"    t\t\t    x\t\t    y\t\t    V\t\t   dx_dt\t   dy_dt\n%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t %lf\n",t,x,y,Vaux,Cxx*x-Cxy*x*y,Cyx*x*y-Cyy*y);
    
    #ifdef EULER
            for(t=0;t<=MAX;t+=DT) // Este bucle representa el "tiempo" transcurrido.
            {
                feuler(x,y,&xaux,&yaux);
    
                x=xaux;
                y=yaux;
    
                V=Cyx*x-Cyy*log(x)+Cxy*y-Cxx*log(y);
    
                fprintf(f,"%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",t,x,y,V);
    
            }
    #else
            for(t=0;t<MAX;t+=DT)
            {
                fverlet(x,y,&xaux,&yaux);
    
                x=xaux;
                y=yaux;
    
                V=Cyx*x-Cyy*log(x)+Cxy*y-Cxx*log(y);
    
                fprintf(f,"%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",t,x,y,V);
            }
    #endif
            V=Cyx*x-Cyy*log(x)+Cxy*y-Cxx*log(y);
    
            printf("V_i=%lf\nV_f=%lf\n",Vaux,V);
        }
    
        fclose(f);
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    void feuler(double xn, double yn, double *xnext, double *ynext) {

    double dx_dt, dy_dt;

    dx_dt = Cxx * xn - Cxy * xn * yn;
    dy_dt = Cyx * xn * yn - Cyy * yn;

    *xnext = xn + dx_dt * DT;
    

    *ynext = yn + dy_dt * DT;
    

    return;
}

void fverlet(double xn, double yn, double *xnext, double *ynext) {

    double dx_dt, dy_dt;
    double dx_dt2, dy_dt2;
    double xmed, ymed;

    dx_dt = Cxx * xn - Cxy * xn * yn;
    dy_dt = Cyx * xn * yn - Cyy * yn;

    dx_dt2 = Cxx * dx_dt - Cxy + (dy_dt * xn + yn * dx_dt);
    dy_dt2 = Cyx * (dy_dt * xn + yn * dx_dt) - Cyy * dy_dt;

    *xnext = xn + dx_dt * DT + dx_dt2 * DT * DT * 0.5;

    *ynext = yn + dy_dt * DT + dy_dt2 * DT * DT * 0.5;
   

    return;
}
```

Comment: Note that `if    return;` in function `feuler()` is a syntax error and it won't compile. What two values does V oscillate between? Is it a symptom of inherently inaccurate floating point arithmetic?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The if return is a mstake posting the message. It oscilates between -0.516128 and -0.599434.

Comment: @Ander Gabarrus, Both `xmed, ymed` set in `fverlet()`, but never used.  Please post true code.

Comment: Sorry, I had some mistakes posting the message, now I think that is correctly posted.

Comment: Nothing you ask is in any way related to choice of programming language. A quick glance i'd say your timestep is to large to obtain a good solution, and you expression for `V` is wrong. Should be `Cyx*x-Cyy*log(Cyx/Cyy*x)+Cxy*y-Cxx*log(Cxy/Cyy*y)`. 
If you see negative values for either population then you have a bug somewhere, and you should fix that.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I dont know what is causing the problem in the algorithm, I still get wrong values that make the V value undifend, I get this result -1.#IND00. This happends when I use a lot of iterations, if I use less iterations I dont get this result.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, OP's oscillating data and wiki link [Lotka–Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I made a representation of my results, and I get the next image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDuv9.png. I get these results with 400 iterations, if I do more iterations the program doesnt work.